# How can I give a MS Account only access to certain SharePoint folders?

Tags: access

I'm an MS Office Administrator in my company, and I was asked to create an account for an external freelancer that would help us with Marketing Measures. Now, we want that he only has access to two Folders within our SharePoint structure.

I have tried creating a group, adding this one user to this group, and then giving this group access to these folders, but they will still have access to all files. I can restrict certain access, but that would take longer as I only want to permit two folders.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.